# Stone representation theorem and right(or left-) one-sided ideals in a ring

Tags: representation-theory, ideals

Consider Marshall Stone's [representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone's_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras):

I would like to know in which specific way, if any, it is connected with the determination of right or left one-sided ideals in a ring. Simple examples are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can tell you a bit about the ideals of the Boolean algebra you are representing, yes. When the Boolean algebra is representable by finitely many copies of $F_2$, then you can recover all ideals: every ideal of $\prod _{i=1}^n F_2$ is of the form $\prod _{i=1}^n I_i$ where each $I_i$ is either $\{0\}$ or $F_2$.

When there are infinitely many copies of $F_2$, it is no longer so easy to describe the ideals.

Strictly one-sided ideals are irrelevant in Boolean algebras since Boolean algebras are all commutative, and all ideals are two-sided.