# Inquiry into operator precedence grammar

Tags: ring-theory, terminology, computer-science, formal-languages, formal-grammar

I have come accross something called operator precedence grammar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_grammar and I would like to know about the specific mathematical properties is presents. In particular, I would be interested in knowing whether it is a kind of Polish notation (if not, in which ways it deviates from that), and also whether it might be useful for representing right ideals in a ring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've noticed this pattern in this question and in [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1340480/29335) and [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1423373/29335) where you ask if semirandom topics are useful with right ideals. I don't want to discourage this line of inquiry totally, but I hope you can stop using the "throw things against the wall and see what sticks" approach. It is pretty inefficient and is not producing very fruitful answers. Pick up any book on applied abstract algebra or representations of algebras to get a better idea of how ideals are used and how they can be modeled.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know about the specific mathematical properties is presents.

From what I have gleaned [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=uKygBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&dq=%22operator+precedence+grammar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBWoVChMIkMOqyJ_vxwIVgVc-Ch1KOA7z#v=onepage&q=%22operator%20precedence%20grammar%22&f=false), an operator precedence grammar is a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) on a grammar with special properties (outlined in the first link). The idea is that they define something like the order of operations for arithmetic expressions in integers (where multiplication takes precedence over addition, etc.) More broadly speaking it is a special binary relation on the grammar.

> I would be interested in knowing whether it is a kind of Polish notation

The grammar is not a notation any more than the statement "$2$ is less than $4$" is a notation. If you are asking whether or not authors *use* any sort of Polish notation when they talk about precedences, then the answer is *maybe*. An author can choose to use such a notation or not. The book I linked to above uses infix notation, not prefix or postfix notation. In any case, *notation* does not change the meaning of what an operator precedence grammar is.

> and also whether it might be useful for representing right ideals in a ring.

I am a ring theorist, but I haven't heard of any connections to this, nor can I immediately spot any connection to ideals or rings.